# Proper name for the generalized binomial distribution with two trials?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, terminology

Two Bernoulli trials are performed, first with success probability $p_1$ and second with success probability $p_2 \not=p_1$. The resulting distribution for the number of positive outcomes is (obviously),

$P_2=p_1 p_2$, $P_1=(1-p_1)(1-p_2)$ and $P_2=1-P_0-P_2$.

I need a name for this distribution which is as informative as possible. Is there a better alternative than a *generalized binomial distribution*? This question is part of an earlier SE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220234/pmf-of-a-generalization-of-binomial-distribution) but it is not in the focus and didn't receive an answer.

(Sorry if the questions sounds boring, but I'm writing a paper and want to be right with terminology).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a Poisson binomial distribution. You can find useful information about it on Wikipedia.

Comment: +1. Never heard of this one... I guess one learns new things every day... :)

Comment: It comes up occasionally on both the stats and math SE sites. It's a handy one to know.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit Based on OP Comments**

Actually, I realised that the sum of two bernoulli rvs with different ps will result in *under*dispersion, so perhaps underdispersed?

If you don't want to be associated with dispersion models, then why not "[Heterogeneous Binomial Sum](http://my.ilstu.edu/~mxu2/teachingISU/Balakrishnan&Xu-MMT&TFCC-8.pdf)", its clearer than *generalized binomial*, as there are several ways you could generalize it.

Comment: Thanks, but this probably won't help. The variability of $p_i$ in my case is deterministically  tuned, and some data points for $P_n$'s even go beyond the generalized/overdispersed binomial constraint. Here is the physics context: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61835

Comment: @Slaviks the p's don't need to be random, and they don't need to have a particular distribution. All that matters is that each Bernoulli trial does not have the same p. In your case, you have a simple prior distribution.

Comment: @Slaviks see revised response.